# Is there an easier/shorter way to filter this kind of code in Django's template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

In my template, I have

```
Vendor:
    {% if order.vendor %}
        {{ order.vendor.name }}
    {% else %}
        Not assigned yet.
    {% endif %}<br />
Quote:
    {% if order.quote %}
        ${{ order.quote }}
    {% else %}
        No quote yet.
    {% endif %}<br />
```

I know I could probably do a simplier version with `{{ value|default:"nothing" }}`, but how would that apply to the 2nd case with Quote? Because the default version should also hide the `$`. Otherwise it will say `$No quote yet.`. Hmmm... maybe there is a way to use the Django's `humanize` framework with $ symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well depending on how your values are stored for order.quote I'd probably personally approach this with a custom filter and replace it with something like `{{ order.quote|currency|default:"No quote yet" }}`

Where currency is a custom template filter defined (roughly) like:

```
import decimal
@register.filter
def currency(val):)
    try:
        return '$%s' % cents / decimal.Decimal(100.00)
    except TypeError:
        return ''
```

This of course assume you are storing quotes as integers rather than floats.  Some localization could be thrown in as well for non US values

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing it the right way.